# Visual Studio 2015: Destination wwwroot/css/site.css not written because no source files were found.

Tags: gruntjs, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to use grunt in my ASP project, but for whatever reasons have get a stupid warning-message from Visual Studio. 
How you can see down, the bower-task has been executed, but haven't uglify- and less-tasks. Gruntfile.js and folder "wwwroot" are in the same folder. What's wrong ?

**This is console output in Visual Studio 2015:**

```js
> cmd.exe /c grunt -b "c:\T\BW\src\BW" --gruntfile "c:\T\BW\src\BW\gruntfile.js" bower
Running "bower:install" (bower) task
>> Installed bower packages
>> Copied packages to c:\T\BW\src\BW\wwwroot\lib
Done, without errors.
Process terminated with code 0.
> cmd.exe /c grunt -b "c:\T\BW\src\BW" --gruntfile "c:\T\BW\src\BW\gruntfile.js" uglify_default
Running "uglify:uglify_target" (uglify) task
Process terminated with code 0.
>> Destination wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.js not written because src files were empty.
>> No files created.
Done, without errors.
> cmd.exe /c grunt -b "c:\T\BW\src\BW" --gruntfile "c:\T\BW\src\BW\gruntfile.js" less
Running "less:dev" (less) task
>> Destination wwwroot/css/site.css not written because no source files were found.
Done, without errors.
Process terminated with code 0.
```

**This is my gruntfile.js:**

```js
    grunt.initConfig({
        bower: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    targetDir: "wwwroot/lib",
                    layout: "byComponent",
                    cleanTargetDir: false
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            uglify_target: {
                files: {
                    "wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.js":["src/angular.min.js"]
                }
            }
        },
        less: {
            dev: {
                files: {
                    "wwwroot/css/site.css": ["less/site.less"]
                },
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                }
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["bower:install"]);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-bower-task");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-less");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure `"wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.js":["src/angular.min.js"]` is correct in your uglify step?  Uglify is for minifying files, so it would seem as if you have the destination and source parameters reversed.  You are also getting the message `Destination wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.js not written because src files were empty.` which would seem to indicate that as well.

The less step seems correct, but it can't find the less file you are trying to compile.  Are you sure that site.less exists in a less folder?

Here is the less portion of the grunt file I just wrote, and it seems to work well, although getting the sourcemap to actually generate is still an issue.  This is pretty much an exact equivalent of VS 2013 with Web Essentials installed.  Compiling all less files in the content folder using autoprefix for the browsers we support, and puts the .css back into the content folder.  It doesn't compile any less file that starts with _, as those are just includes/variables.

```
    less: {
        development: {
            options: {
                paths: ["content"],
                compress: true,
                plugins: [
                        new (require('less-plugin-autoprefix'))({ browsers: ["IE >= 9, firefox > 10, last 2 Chrome versions, last 2 safari versions, last 2 ios versions"], map: { inline: false } })
                ]
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'content',
                src: ['*.less', '!_*.less'],
                dest: 'content',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. Your are right, I've actually swapped the destination and source parameters. **It should be:**
`["src/angular.min.js"] : "wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.js"`. I would mark your answer as correct.